# When launching simulator Error:Invalid <arg> tag: turtlebot_description

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys I'm trying to run turtlebot with Gazebo(empty_world) but none of them were working
Need help!!!

this is Output when i run this command

```
       roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch 

... logging to /home/ss/.ros/log/576cd2c2-8ef2-11e2-9158-00e04c534458/roslaunch-ubuntu-9864.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

while processing /home/ss/workspace/sandbox/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/_kobuki.launch:
Invalid <arg> tag: turtlebot_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ss/workspace/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks. 

Arg xml is <arg default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" name="urdf_file"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58360/when-launching-simulator-error:invalid-%3Carg%3E-tag:-turtlebot_description/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on 2013-03-23**:
It seems that i dont have urdf files in my system,

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-04-06**:
I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. I just found the solution, you also need to install the turtlebot package the turtlebot_simulator alone isn't enough.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-turtlebot
```

---

Originally posted by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) with karma: 248 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-06**:
Ticketed: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/issues/7

**Comment by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on 2013-04-06**:
Hey hi are you getting gazebo without any errors, i mean launched successfully.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-06**:
Turtlebot simulation in Groovy is not yet supported. It´s targeted for Hydro. If we get it working earlier, we will let you. Join the [TurtleBot SIG mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-turtlebot) to stay up to date!